# How to pass a variable to another jQuery tab?

Tags: jquery, variables

i have some simple jquery tabs:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
<div class="demo">
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
        <ul>
    <li>
            <div><?php id='123'; ?></div>
    <a id="test" class="link-image1" href="#tabs-2?id=123">test</a>
            </li>

    <li>
            <div><?php id='234'; ?></div>
    <a id="test" class="link-image2" href="#tabs-2id=234">test</a>
            </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
            <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){ echo $_GET['id']; } ?>
            <div id="placeholder"></div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

what i want is to pass a variable, `id`, to some other tab.

I'm not concern with making the tabs work, in case they don't,  but only on passing that variable

is this possible?

edit:
i have this javascript:

```
$(".link-image").click(ajax_request);
$('#placeholder').load("/test.php?id=1234556");
```

the idea is that when i click on `.link-image` link i will change the tab and send a ajax request to load something there, but i need to pass the `id` variable with it

edit:

when i click on `link-image1` i want to pass the `id` from the same `li` and so on

Comment: What do you mean with "Pass a variable to another tab"?

Comment: Will the variable change through some other JS code after the page has loaded?

Comment: As per Rob's question, I don't see anything being passed around.

Comment: i am getting confused myself :) i believe that the `id` is available anyway...

Comment: Is the id you're after in the tab that is being clicked or in the tab you are switching to?

Comment: Your shown code is invalid (`<?php id="123"; ?>`. If you want to get the `href` attribute, use `.attr('href')`

Comment: i have a tab with multiple links and id's, when i click on a link i want to send that link to the `#placeholder` and change the tab to the second one

Comment: If you show your real syntaxerror-free code, I would bother improving it, so that it works.

Comment: @Rob W, that fix it, if you want post your answer and ill choose it as the good one. sometimes i over think these simple things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).attr('href')` to get the `href` attribute.

```
$(".link-image").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');        // Example #tabs-2?id=123
    var id = link.match(/id=(\d+)/)[1];     // Matches 123
    // continue with your function logic

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){ echo $_GET['id']; } ?>
```

into any or all tabs, you're just echoing out the ID.

If you want it as a variable available to javascript just add

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){ echo "var myid=".(int)$_GET['id'].';'; } ?>
```

at the top inside the  tags and you'll have a myid set to your value.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but I am not sure how you want to use this variable.

Do you want it to switch to the tab with an `id=$_GET['id']`?